# What connection string to use to connect to network server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, instance, connections

I have a database on my computer running on SQL Server Express 2014, and I'd like other computers connected to my network to be able to connect to it using a C# program I wrote.

I've done the following:

**1. turned off windows firewall.** I know I don't need to do this completely, but I'm just debugging.

**2. enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager on the machine running the instance.**

I can't change this for all machines. On the computer I'm trying to connect from, but not the computer hosting the database, I can't enable this. I'm not sure if that's a problem. However, on my machine I've enabled pretty much everything and restarted everything.

**3. Remote connections are allowed**

Using a `.UDL` file to test the connection, I found that on my computer, if I select `MyComputerName` as the server, I don't see my database listed. But if I enter `MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS`, I do see the database and can connect to it with integrated windows security.

But if I log on another computer and use a `.UDL` to test the connection. I can connect if I enter `MyComputerName` as the server, but if I try to enter `MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS` as the server, it tries really hard but then tells me

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Again, on my computer using the following connection strings work

```
Server=MyMachine\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;
Server=MyMachine\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

But on another computer on the network, I get the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But I know that the the server is allowed remote connections and that the instance name is running, so I'm stuck. Any ideas of where to go from here?

Comment: Can you connect to the instance from SSMS. you can install it on one of your machines to test connectivity

Comment: Is [Allow remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) enabled ?

Comment: @Kin Yes it is.

Comment: @JamesAnderson on the machine I'm testing it on, it doesn't have SSMS installed. It has the instance running and the import/export wizard, the configuration manager, error and usage reporting, etc., but not the management studio. I'm not an admin on that machine so I can't install it. Do you think that's the problem? It can connect if I change the connection string to attach a local db from a .mdf so I'm not sure that's it.

Comment: Can you look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a8f2e64-74cf-46f2-b2be-bbb08b1502cb/re-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlreportingservices) post and check things that you are missing. The error is very generic.

Comment: No. You could try a conneection from PowerShell to see what errors it gives. The following link explains how to do that from a machine without SQL Server installed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/04/13/run-a-sql-server-command-from-powershell-without-the-sql-server-provider.aspx

Comment: Is the SQL Server Browser service running? It's needed to connect to a named instance. And what is the exact service name on your pc ? MSSQLSERVER or MSSQL$EXPRESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Maybe someone could expand on this, because I don't fully understand it.

When I opened Management Studio as `MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS` which I normally do, attached the database there, I couldn't access it through `MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS` in the connection string.

However, when I reopened Managment Studio as `MyMachineName`, attached the database there, and removed the `\SQLEXPRESS` from my connection string, I can now access it.

Problem solved.